# Как получить значение элемента из одного частичного представления и передать его в другое частичное представление, без нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть главное представление в котором отображаются 2 частичных представления

```
@model MyProject.Models.MainModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MainView";
}
@Html.Partial("_PartialView1")
@Html.Partial("_PartialView2")
```

1 частичное представление:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Model1
<h2>_PartialView1</h2>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.value1)
```

2 частичное представление:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Model2
<h2>_PartialView2</h2>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.value2)
```

Метод контроллера

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialViews(){
        return PartialView("_PartialView1");
    }
```

(Код условный и упрощенный) 
Как получить значение из первого `TextBoxFor` и передать его во второй без нажатий на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("value1"));
    console.log(document.getElementById("value2"));
    document.getElementById("value2").value = document.getElementById("value1").value; 
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: странно, но не работает( можно лучше задавать значение из value1 переменно? И ещё я использую фреймворк DevExpress и там надо получать значение через GetNumber()

Comment: @naughtyBit что в консоли браузера?

Comment: спасибо большое, разобрался на основе вашего кода